# Batch Converting Apple SCN files into DAE

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I have this test iOS app that basically brute force export SCN files out of the app, basically at around 60 SCN files per second.

Since I do not have any better way to export this on device simulation, this is my current solution.

Anyhow, is there a known way to batch convert SCN file format into DAE Collada? I can do manual export using XCode, but seems to work once at time. Not gonna be fun.

Is there a quick way using Playground to actually do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the `xcrun` command to run `scntool` and provide it input/output files, then the format.

```
xcrun scntool --convert fileIn.scn --output fileOut.dae --format dae
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this seems to be it~ I didn't think of XCode command line~ Cheers.