# Convert .scn scene to usdz (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, usdz

I have lost a lot of sleep over this (in the past 3 years).
I was hooping that Apple would at least be able to export its own .scn Scenes to USDZ without too much problems.

Has anyone been successful in exporting a .scn scene to USDZ **from within an app**?

I have tried this but to no avail:

https://github.com/piemonte/obj2usdz

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this:

[Batch Converting Apple SCN files into DAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365903/batch-converting-apple-scn-files-into-dae)

```
xcrun scntool --convert fileIn.scn --output fileOut.dae --format dae
```

Or this:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/104553

They mention a number of ways such as converting to a dae first, and then using the free converter.

Comment: Thanks. I meant how to export to USDZ from within an app (I have an .scn created by user and want to export it to USDZ just like exporting to .dae or .obj etc).

Comment: @gm_ no idea. Maybe just upload to a server which has the tool installed, convert it and download.